# Window Paste Event Listener not firing in IE 11

Tags: javascript, typescript, window, clipboard, addeventlistener

This is my code that works perfectly in chrome

```
public ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('paste', this.InsertNewRowsBeforePaste.bind(this));
  }
```

In Chrome only this will get fired if the user selects Ctrl+V in my component which in this case is a custom grid

```
InsertNewRowsBeforePaste(event) {       
    console.log(event);
    console.log(window);
    // gets data from clipboard and converts it to an array (1 array element for each line)
    let clipboardData = event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent['clipboardData'].getData('text');
    if (!clipboardData) {
      clipboardData = window['clipboardData'].getData('Text');
    }  
}
```

The problem is in IE11 the InserNewRowsBeforePaste is never fired as my console never logs the event or the window. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to capture the key down event in IE that will mimic the Ctrl + V behavior then you can access the clipboard from there

```
this.global = this.renderer.listen('document', 'keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey === true && event.key === 'v') {
          const clipboardData = window['clipboardData'].getData('Text');
          if (clipboardData) {
            // Call any method to manipulate the clipboard data here
          }
        }
      });
```